# Adjoint of a linear mapping mapping into a product of Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

I am self studying adjoint operators on Banach spaces.  The adjoint of a linear mapping $L:X \rightarrow Y$, where $X,Y$ are Banach spaces, is a unique mapping
\begin{equation}
L^*:Y^{*} \rightarrow X^*
\end{equation}
defined by
\begin{equation}
L^*y^* = y^* \circ L.
\end{equation}
The above definition can be found on Page 98 of Functional Analysis by Rudin.  My question concerns the case where the mapping goes to a product of Banach spaces.  For example, let $T:X \rightarrow Y_1 \times Y_2$ be a linear mapping, with $X,Y_{1},Y_2$ Banach spaces.
Following the above definition, the adjoint of $T$ would be
\begin{equation}
T^*:(Y_{1} \times Y_{2})^*  \rightarrow X^*.
\end{equation}
Since the dual of a product space is a product space of the duals, the above is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
T^*:Y_{1}^* \times Y_{2}^*  \rightarrow X^*.
\end{equation}
My question regards how to explicitly define $T^*$. The adjoint is itself a linear operator so my intuition says that
\begin{equation}
T^*(y_{1}^*,y_{2}^*) =  y_{1}^* \circ T + y_{2}^* \circ T 
\end{equation}
but I have no proof of this.   Is this correct?  Any proof or reference would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question reduces to understand in what sense is $Y_1^*\times Y_2^*$ the dual of $Y_1\times Y_2$. After all, an ordered pair of linear functionals is not a linear functional.

If $f:Y_1\times Y_2\to\mathbb C$ is linear, we can write $f(y_1,y_2)=f_1(y_1)+f_2(y_2)$, where $f_j\in Y_j^*$ is given by
$$
f_1(y)=f(y_1,0),\qquad\qquad f_2(y)=f(0,y_2).
$$
This induces a natural isomorphism $(Y_1\times Y_2)^*\to Y_1^*\times Y_2^*$, where the norm on $Y_1^*\times Y_2^*$ will depend on the norm you gave to $Y_1\times Y_2$:
$$
\|(f,g)\|=\sup\{|f(y)+g(z)|:\ \|(y,z)\|=1\}. 
$$ With this point of view,
$$
T^*(f,g)(x)=(f,g)(Tx)=f(T_1x)+g(T_2x).
$$
That is,
$$
T^*(f,g)=f\circ T_1+g\circ T_2,
$$
where $T_1:X\to Y_1$ and $T_2:X\to Y_2$ are given by $Tx=(T_1x,T_2x)$.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  You were right I was not appreciating the linearity on $Y_{1} \times Y_{2}$.