# Linear Independence of a linear mapping and injectivity of the adjoint.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

I am curious as to whether there are any conditions on a vector-valued linear operator that imply injectivity of its adjoint.    This is in part a continuation of my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482442/adjoint-of-a-linear-mapping-mapping-into-a-product-of-banach-spaces/4482475#4482475).  For reference, let $T:X \rightarrow  Y_{1} \times \ldots \times Y_{n} $, with $T \in L(X,Y_{1} \times \ldots \times Y_{n})$ and $X,Y_{i}$ Banach spaces.
The adjoint of $T$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&T^{*}: Y_{1}^* \times \ldots \times Y_{n}^* \rightarrow X^* \\
&T^{*}(y_{1}^*,\ldots,y_{n}^*)(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}^{*} \circ T_{i}x.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Setting the above summation equal to $0$, this $\textbf{looks}$ similar to the definition of linear independence.  However, for common Banach spaces such as $L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$ spaces, $p \neq 2$, the expression $y_{i}^{*} \circ T_{i}x$ becomes the integration of the product of some $L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^{q}(\mathbb{R})$ functions.  To the best of my knowledge, sums of integrals are not necessarily linearly independent, even if their integrands are.

This leads to my question.  Are there any properties of $T_{i}$ (perhaps linear independence in combination with something else) that can allow us to conclude injectivity of the adjoint?  I have been reading Rudin's Functional Analysis. Chapter 4 (specifically Theorem 4.15) gives conditions for the injectivity of $T^*$ but this requires the strong assumption that $T$ is surjective.

Comment: There is a corollary after 4.12 that says that $T^*$ is injective iff $R(T)$ is dense.

Comment: do I understand correctly that your adjoint is just a representation of the dual under some induced iso to the dual via a non-degenerate bilinear form? if so, yes, being an epi should do the trick

Comment: @daw Thanks for the comment, I should have been more clear.  I have seen that corollary that your referencing, but showing the range of a map is dense still seems like a big ask.  Do you know of any quick approaches to showing an operator has dense range?

Comment: @Enkidu Forgive me, my Algebra background is not strong.  I think the answer to your question is yes.  There is a natural isomorphism between $(Y_{1} \times \ldots \times Y_{n})^*$ and $Y_{1}^* \times \ldots \times Y_{n}^*$. This isomorphism is given (in the case $n=2$) by the mapping $L: Y_{1}^* \times Y_{2}^* \rightarrow (Y_{1} \times Y_{2})^*$ defined by $L(f,g)(x,y) = f(x) + g(y)$. I believe this is the non-degenerate bilinear form you're referencing.  In regards to epimorphisms, are there any properties/conditions that can tell us if a mapping is an epi?

Comment: yes, I think it should just be surjectivity, might be able to hunt it through so later today, but if in the end $T^*$ is just the morphism $\_ \circ T:(\Prod_{i=1}^n Y_i)^* \to X^*$ then your question translates precisely to $T$ being an epimorphism, which usually just means  that it is surjective. However, $\mathbb{L}_p$ spaces can have awkward properties in those regards. So maybe it does not need to be surjective, but dense in the image suffices. Topology does weird stuff.